# Overload input (>>) operator to take enum strings

Tags: c++, input, operator-overloading

```
enum shuffle_mode {IN, OUT};
istream& operator>> (istream& in, shuffle_mode& shuffle) {
    int a;
    in >> a;
    if (a==1) {shuffle=IN;}
    if (a==2) {shuffle=OUT;}
}
```

I would like to modify this operators overload so that it is able to directly take IN or OUT as input instead of their corresponding numbers in enum.

In a perfect scenario it would look something like this:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in, shuffle_mode shuffle) {
in >> shuffle;
}
```

Comment: Not really possible to do your "perfect scenario". If you want to read a string `"IN"` and convert that to enum value, you'll have to implement such mapping (and this would be one of the few places where macros are useful). If you want to read `int`s, then in this particular case it would be enough to do `shuffle = static_cast<shuffle_mode>(a + 1);`, provided that `a + 1` is valid enum value.

Comment: I've never thought about it that way. You want to pass by value into `shuffle`. Where does the resulting `shuffle` go in your perfect scenario?

Comment: You want to be able to input `IN/OUT` as strings and have it convert to your enum?

Comment: You said you didn't want `shuffle_mode& shuffle` but `shuffle_mode shuffle`.

Comment: Why is that a perfect scenario? That does that accomplish for you?

Comment: In the argument I actually forgot the &. It should be "shuffle_mode& shuffle"

By pefect scenario I meant that I basically want to input a string "IN" or "OUT" and the have the operator >> convert it into a shuffle_mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said

> In a perfect scenario it would look something like this:
>
> ```
> istream& operator>> (istream& in, shuffle_mode shuffle) {
>   in >> shuffle;
> }
> ```

That would be a problem. It's going to result in infinite recursion and stack overflow.

You can use:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& in, shuffle_mode& shuffle) {
    std::string token;
    in >> token;
    if ( token == "IN" || token == "1" ){shuffle=IN;}
    else if ( token == "OUT" || token == "2" ){shuffle=OUT;}
    else { /* Error */ }

    return in;
}
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question (never really did overloading that much) but why do we return in?

Comment: @Sebastian, any function whose return type is not `void` must return a valid value. In your case, it has to return `in` to make it idiomatic.

Comment: @Sebastian, that will allow you to chain use of the `>>` operator.

Comment: @Sebastian The chaining R. Sahu talks about is what makes `cin >> var1 >> var2;` work. `cin >> var1` returns a reference to `cin` which is used in `cin >> var2`.

Comment: Why is the proposed solution not an infinite recursion since `>>` is being used internally otherwise? Does `return in` make the difference?

Comment: @gonidelis the function uses `>>` internally but it is used to read a `std::string`. That does not lread to infinite recursion. Use of `return in;` is not a factor in causing or stopping infinite recursion. But it helps in chaining of calls to `operator>>`.